# PHP - Generate dropdown List of images -> Copy image to new Dir -> Delete original image

Tags: php, image, file, jpeg

I have a drop down list that generates all files in a folder, which is working. But i would like to only see .jpg files and also i would like to exclude one file from the list as it is a place holder image lets call it "0001_Place_Holder.jpg".

The second part to this is that i want to pick a file from the dropdown list and copy it to a New folder then delete the original image.

this is "move_files_general.php"  // which generates my dropdown list

```
<?php
$dirname = "general_2";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form action="move_general.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="file2">';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != ".."))
    {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
    }
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Move To Quality" class="submit" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

This is "move_general.php" // which should copy the file then delete the original

```
<?php
$dirpath = "general_2";
$dirpath_2 = "quality_2";
$file_to_move = $_GET['file2'];
copy("$dirpath.'/'.$file_to_move", "$dirpath_2.'/'.$file_to_move") or       die("Unable to copy");
if (copy("$dirpath.'/'.$file_to_move", "$dirpath_2.'/'.$file_to_move")) {
unlink("$dirpath.'/'.$file_to_move");
    if ( unlink ($dirpath.'/'.$file_to_move) ) {
            echo $file_to_move . " deleted.";
        echo '<script>parent.window.location.reload(true);</script>';
    } else {
    echo "Error.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: it hits the die("Unable to copy") in the "Copy" line

Comment: Try to use absolute paths. Did you set the permissions to your folder? If there is an exception, you should find  it in your log-files

Comment: The folder does have permission set correctly, i have a php file that has a drop down and on submit deletes files. seems to be something with the copy line.  i tried absolute file paths in the '$dirpath and $dirpath_2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Thanks for your answers, and help. *Alex Odenthal*, that worked for the 1st part. i tried everything to get the 2nd part to work. I finally rewrote it a different way and it's working now, I must have had something wrong , somewhere.

Here is my fixed "move_files_general.php"

```
<?php
$dirname = "general";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<form action="move_general.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="file2">';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "0001_Place_Holder_DO_NOT_DELETE.jpg"))
    {
if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ==='jpg'){
    echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";

}
}

}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Move To Quality1" class="submit" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Here is my fixed "move_general.php"

```
<?php
$file_to_move = $_GET['file2'];
$source = "general/$file_to_move";
$dest = "quality/$file_to_move";
copy($source, $dest);
if (copy($source, $dest)) {
    unlink($source);
            if(file_exists($source)) {
            unlink($source); }
    else {
            echo "Deleted.";
            }
        }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would test the filename if its extension is jpg and if it is not equal to your placeholder name.

```
if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "0001_Place_Holder.jpg"))
{
    if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ==='jpg'){
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
    }
}
```

For the second issue: try to set the folder permissions to 777 for testing purpose. Also echo the strings that you pass to copy(string1,string2) in order to check if something is wrong in there.